# Como evito que un th ocupe mucho espacio en un tr

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo una tabla con unos tr y th, y el problema es que el th (lo de azul) ocupa mucho espacio y quiero que en el td tengo mucho mas para la información a ingresar.

Adjunto el codigo e imagen

```
 <table style="width: 100%">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3" scope="col">Información del Cliente</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Empresa:</th>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Nombre del Usuario:</th>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">Departamento:</th>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A tus **th y td** en CSS agrégales un **width: 50%;**, dependiendo la cantidad de celdas lo reduces o aumentas, con eso le das un tamaño fijo a cada celda, si necesitas ejemplo me dices.

Comment: Sumado a lo que dice antonio le podes añadir un ``max-width: XXXpx`` de esta manera cuando el 50% sea mayor a XXX, ya no va a seguir creciendo.